# Insert data in a parametrization table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to INSERT new data to a parametrization table. It is an INSERT INTO clause type problem.

Table A Staging

```
Id    Owner           Brand        CreationDate CreationUser
1     Shakespeare   Rolls Royce      2011-04-22    Burbage
3     Aristotle     Tesla            2014-12-25    Plato
9     Einstein      MayFlower        2015-01-01    Bohr
```

Table B parametrization

```
Id   BrandDescription 
1     Rolls Royce
2     Tesla          
3     MayFlower
```

Table C after mapping the id of Brand (table b) to the Brand of table A

```
Id    Owner           BrandId      CreationDate CreationUser
1     Shakespeare       1           2011-04-22    Burbage
3     Aristotle         2           2014-12-25    Plato
9     Einstein          3           2015-01-01    Bohr
```

Now suppose that two new records enters in the table A staging.

```
  Id    Owner           Brand         CreationDate CreationUser
  1     Shakespeare   Rolls Royce      2011-04-22    Burbage
  3     Aristotle     Tesla            2014-12-25    Plato
  9     Einstein      MayFlower        2015-01-01    Bohr
  17    John Bardeen  Tesla2           2017-01-02    Nikola
  18    Sanger        Phaeton          2018-03-01    Curie
```

I want to add the two new brands to the parametrization table B... 
so it could be:

```
    Id   BrandDescription  CreationDate  CreationUser
    1     Rolls Royce       2011-04-22      Automatic
    2     Tesla             2014-12-25      Automatic
    3     MayFlower         2015-01-01      Automatic
    4     Tesla2            2017-01-02      Automatic    
    5     Phaeton           2018-03-01      Automatic
```

I have tried with:

```
    If not exists (select 1 from 
                    from  table_b tb 
                    inner join table_a ta on tb.BrandDescription=ta.Brand)      insert into table_b
values (ta.Brand,getdate(),'Automatic')
```

It throws an error: 
*The multi-part identifier "ta.Brand" could not be bound.*

It must check always the parametrization table to check out if there is any brands that appear in the new records of table A staging... so, as Tesla2 and Phaeton did not exist in the old parametrization table they should be inserted. Otherwise, nothing happens.

Just one more new record as

(for table A)

```
Id    Owner           Brand         CreationDate CreationUser
(...)
17    John Bardeen  Tesla2           2017-01-02    Nikola
18    Sanger        Phaeton          2018-03-01    Curie
19    Sagan         Tt:              2019-02-01    Lok
```

If there is a **:** in the brand it should not be inserted in the parametrization table B.

```
If not exists (select 1 
               from table_b tb 
               inner join table_a ta on tb.BrandDescription=ta.Brand and ta.Brand not like '%' + ':' + '%')     
    insert into table_b
    values (ta.Brand,getdate(),'Automatic')
```

the problem is to assign the Brand of table A to the BrandDescription of the parametrization table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do that without if clause, you are trying to access a column (ta.brand) that doesn't exists in the scope of insert statement.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO table_b
SELECT DISTINCT ta.Brand, GetDate(), 'Automatic' --use DISTINCT to return unique row
FROM table_a ta 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b tb on tb.BrandDescription=ta.Brand
WHERE ta.Brand not like '%' + ':' + '%' 
AND tb.ID is NULL --check if row exists in table_b
```

Comment: it threw 0 rows... nothing was added... ah.. in this case we must drop the not in NOT LIKE :) Now it is working.